# Inspecting the body of an HTTP request with gocraft Middleware

Tags: http, go, hmac

I've been using the [gocraft-web](https://github.com/gocraft/web) package so far to do some development on an HTTP service. It's really great because you can stick middleware in it to check for stuff like the presence of a Cookie in the header.

At the moment I am wanting to implement request signing. Getting the client to sign the request is easy enough, but I am wanting to check it for all endpoints with a common piece of middleware. Basically the middleware needs to find the key to check against, compute the request HMAC, and check it against the supplied HMAC (presumably in the `Authorization` Header).

Computing the actual HMAC is really easy in go.

The problem is: reading the message in middleware makes it unavailable to the final endpoint.

The best solution I have come up with (example shown below) is to read everything from the `Request` in the middleware and stuffing it back into a `bytes.Buffer` for later reading. Is there a better way to do this? The current implementation seems a bit hackish.

Reading everything into memory sucks, but I can probably just put my service behind a proxy and limit the size of requests anyways. The actual content will always be pretty small(under 5 kilobytes). The extra copy introduced by this approach is likely to be quite slow, but computing the HMAC of a message is not exactly cheap to begin with.

The advantage to this is that it is transparent: it will work with any other go http code that just expects to read from `Request.Body` without any magic.

I suppose I could be a bit slicker and use a `io.TeeReader`.

This is my solution so far. If you post to localhost:3300 some JSON it prints the sha512 to the terminal in the server process, but also the response is able to contain a listing of the keys & values in it.

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "github.com/gocraft/web"
import "net/http"
import "bytes"
import "crypto/sha512"
import "io"
import "encoding/hex"
import "encoding/json"

type Context struct{}

type echoer struct {
    *bytes.Buffer
}

func (e echoer) Close() error {
    //Just do nothing to make the interface happy
    return nil
}

func middlewareThatLooksAtBody(rw web.ResponseWriter, req *web.Request, next web.NextMiddlewareFunc) {
    var replacement echoer
    replacement.Buffer = &bytes.Buffer{}

    hash := sha512.New()

    hash.Write([]byte(req.Method))
    reader := req.Body

    var bytes []byte = make([]byte, 64)
    for {
        amount, err := reader.Read(bytes)

        fmt.Printf("Read %d bytes\n", amount)

        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            panic(err)
        }
        if amount == 0 {
            break
        }

        hash.Write(bytes)
        replacement.Write(bytes)
    }
    //Is this needed?
    reader.Close()

    //replacement.Seek(0, 0)
    req.Body = replacement

    fmt.Printf("%v\n", hex.EncodeToString(hash.Sum(nil)))

    next(rw, req)
}

func echoJson(rw web.ResponseWriter, req *web.Request) {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(req.Body)
    var obj map[string]interface{}
    err := dec.Decode(&obj)

    if err != nil {
        rw.WriteHeader(http.StatusBadRequest)
        fmt.Fprintf(rw, "%v\n", err)
        return
    }

    for k, v := range obj {
        fmt.Fprintf(rw, "%v = %v\n", k, v)
    }
}

func main() {
    router := web.New(Context{})

    router.Middleware(middlewareThatLooksAtBody)
    router.Post("/", echoJson)
    http.ListenAndServe("localhost:3300", router)

}
```

Comment: I think the only way to avoid storing the body in memory would be to defer the validation till after you've read the body. Then if later in code you read the body it can also compute the HMAC at the same time. Unfortunately (unless you can guarantee that the code reads the body first) that means you will have performed all the actions for a request before validating it, which isn't what you want.

Comment: @Caleb The only other idea I have had is creating a new `struct` which embeds a JSON decoder. All POST requests send JSON + HMAC (if required). The struct could decode the JSON while simultaneously validating it. But that means the implementer of each endpoint has to use a specialized decoder.

Comment: So I wrote a `ValidatingReadCloser`: http://play.golang.org/p/mZ1KsYRzdo, but sadly it won't work because the `json.Decoder` only reads until it finds the first value. (The validation doesn't happen until the request handler function has already finished)

Comment: @Caleb I considered that but did not try it. Why does the `JSON.Decoder` only read until it finds the first value?

Comment: I believe it does this so that you could continue decoding values. Like you could have a stream of: `[1,2,3,4][1,2,3,4]`

Comment: Ok, cool. That approach might work for me then as I expect all `POST` to just contain a single dictionary object. I'm going to benchmark some different ideas I have and see what the benefits and tradeoffs of each one is.

Comment: @Caleb I don't think this really solves the problem but I came up with this http://www.hydrogen18.com/blog/golang-hmac-http.html

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it looks like you need to read all the bytes from the request body, regardless of what your handlers will do.

If so, then you have at least a couple of options that would avoid the extra copy:

1) Store the read contents inside your gocraft context.

2) Do all body data processing and validation in the middleware and store the results of the processing in the context.

Granted, this means that your handlers now must know that they should look for the contents in the context instead of the req.Body.

I think it's a decent trade-off though, given your requirements.